# IE 9 File Upload Issues

Tags: jquery, file, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have a html file input element(). On click the pop up is coming to browse for images. once selected a form with submitted using jquery.

This works fine in chrome, FF and Safari.

But in IE 9 , a JS error is coming in the console saying "script5: access is denied" and not at all going to my controller.

My application is a spring mvc application.

Please let me know the workaround.

Comment: `script5` ? show us your codes.

Comment: Is the form submitted by ajax? IE9 doesn't support the HTML5 fileData spec. If you need ajax support you'll have to use a flash proxy like swfUpload.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I figured it out. I've added a new pop up and that does a form submit. I know thats not what i wanted, but this works.